# The isnull function requires 2 argument(s)

Tags: sql

```
SELECT IIF(ISNULL(MAX((AttTmpInOutFrmMachine.AttId))),0,MAX((AttTmpInOutFrmMachine.AttId)))+1 
FROM AttTmpInOutFrmMachine
```

Comment: It's true, it does. Perhaps you have a question?

Comment: what are tht arguments

Comment: Well, you see, there's this wonderful thing called a "search engine" where you can type in words like `ISNULL` and whatever database product you're using (such as SQL Server) and it should help you find the *documentation*.

Comment: -1 for apparently not even trying to read the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument in `ISNull` is value that will be used when your field data is actually null. Example:

```
IsNUll(someint, 0)
```

the above will return someint if someint not null, otherwise, it will return 0

Comment: SELECT CASE  WHEN ISNULL(MAX(AttTmpInOutFrmMachine.AttId),0) THEN 0 ELSE MAX(AttTmpInOutFrmMachine.AttId)+1 END as a
FROM AttTmpInOutFrmMachine

Answer (score 0):

This is enough

```
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(AttTmpInOutFrmMachine.AttId),0)+1 FROM AttTmpInOutFrmMachine
```

Answer (score 0):

The first is the value that should checked against `null` and the second one is the value with that `null` should be replaced.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/ms184325.aspx) for a exmplanation for ms-sql

> Syntax
>
> ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )
>   Arguments
>
> check_expression  Is the expression to be checked for NULL.
>   check_expression can be of any type. replacement_value  Is the
>
> expression to be returned if check_expression is NULL.
>   replacement_value must be of a type that is implicitly convertible to
>   the type of check_expresssion.

Answer (score 0):

As Syntax for IIF is :

```
IIF ( boolean_expression, true_value, false_value )
```

I think you are looking out for logic like below:

```
SELECT IIF(ISNULL(MAX(AttTmpInOutFrmMachine.AttId),0)=0
           ,0
           ,MAX(AttTmpInOutFrmMachine.AttId))+1 as NextAttId
FROM AttTmpInOutFrmMachine
```